# How to make two documents update each other during real time depending on each other input?

Tags: java, actionevent, documentlistener, readwritelock

Supposedly there are two abstract documents that correspond to JTextFields (Both JTextFields are different variables).

Suppose, user inputs numeric value in JtextField1(document A), it should update the other JTextField2(document B) during run time accordingly. The same goes if user inputs numeric value in JTextField2(Document B) at the same program run time, it should update JTextField1(Document A).

I tried solving this by using Document Listener, however, it will work only on updating one document(either A updates B or vice versa) during run time rather than both (or each other to be precise) as it provides a deadlock. Should I use DocumentFilter for this problem? I am clueless how I would apply it for this situation, though. I tried avoiding deadlock/write lock problem by using FocusListeners and disabling DocumentListener when the field is not in focus, but it was a very naive approach as it totally does not deal with threads(if that is the problem). Would creating a separate thread when the other field is selected suffice?I have no real knowledge in multi threading, though. I would appreciate a some sort of advice on this problem.

code: http://pastebin.com/qqYPXcAf

I m trying to recreate similar GUI functionality of photoshop that updates width/height size in pixels for keeping AR during run time on user input (picture: http://puu.sh/9L07v/c745e85867.png)

Comment: can you break down your question in more readable format plz?

Comment: These data structures are managed by the the one and only GUI Event Thread without locking.  Can you explain the deadlock you are getting?  What is being locked by which threads?

Comment: If the listener for A updates B and vice versa: skip updating if the value in the field to be updated is identical to the new value. This will break the circle. (If that's what you mean by deadlock, which it isn't.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I use DocumentFilter for this problem?

An easier solution is to just share the Document:

```
JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(...);
JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(...);
textField2.setDocument( textField1.getDocument() );
```

Or if you code is doing some kind of calculation so that the two values are different then you can just remove the DocumentListener to avoid looping. So the basic code for the listener on textField2 would be:

```
textField1.getDocument().removeDocumentListener(...);
textField1.setText( ... );
textField1.addDocumentListener(...);
```

So know when you update the text in text field one it will not notify textField2.

Comment: my code is definitely dealing with some computation. Basically if one documents gets updated by the user, the second one has to get updated accordingly and vice versa. Problem is if I use two document listeners and user tries to do another update on document, document gets write locked. Some people suggested to use DocumentFilter, but as far as I am aware it is not really accurate to use for cross-component document editing during run time which is what I am trying to achieve have two documents being able to update each other along with user input without getting write locked.

Comment: Also, I tried removing documentListener to avoid looping and write lock, however, for some reason documentListener does not get removed.

Comment: A DocumentFilter is not the solution. If you are not removing the DocumentListener then you have a problem with your code. Fix the problem and the suggestion should work. Create a simple `SSCCE` to test the concept. Get the `SSCCE` working and then apply the solution to your real code.

Comment: I made my code work and you were right the only problem I was having is that I did not defined private listeners as a variables so I could add and remove them properly, instead I was making anonymous listeners and was trying to remove listener that did not even exist. Thank you for your help, took a while realizing it, but I did it.